# Redux-firestore with React-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

Can redux-firestore be used with react-native (expo)? Any special setup to take note if can?

I plan to use react-redux-firebase n understand react-redux-firebase can be used with react native. I like to find out if the same goes for redux-firestore.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @cheeesus, i have not proceeded to test that out yet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, redux-firestore can absolutely be used with react-native.  I mostly think of redux-firestore as a "subproject" to [react-redux-firebase](http://react-redux-firebase.com/) (RRF), providing the same capabilities you have in RRF for Firebase Realtime Database, but instead using Firestore database (it's not 100% accurate, but good enough :) ).

I mostly follow the RRF documentation, including the stuff that describes [using RRF with React Native](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/react-native.html).

Both the Web/JS and Native Modules instructions point to [sample configuration](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase#use) that include code you can uncomment to enable Firestore.